# Can I apply for Schengen visa from German consulate (Germany will be my entry port)though I will be staying for more nights in Poland?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, applications

I have booked a package tour for travelling in Europe from Bangalore. My entry port will be Germany where I will be staying for 2 nights and I will be staying in Poland for 3 nights. I want to know if I can apply for Visa from Germany( can apply for Visa in Bangalore) instead of Poland since we have to travel to Mumbai from Bangalore in order apply for Visa.

Answer (score 1):

You must apply at the consulate for the **main destination** of your trip. If there are no special factors, that would be the place where you stay *longest*. Are you doing anything in Germany that could be convincingly argued as the *main purpose* of the trip?

If not, applying for a German visa would mean that the German consulate will turn your application down because they're not responsible for your trip.